# Redirect to nested route with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

When I try to Redirect to a nested url, it seems to go in infinite loop.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/nse" component={App} />
</Router>
```

In the App component,

```
if(visibleContainerProp == 4){          
  return <Redirect to={`${match.url}/stockdetails/${searchticker}`} />
}
```

Here, visibleContainerProp is read from state as mentioned in the docs
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

I am setting the visibleContainerProp to 4 every time user selects a ticker from search box and trying to Redirect to the above url. But it fails.

In the browser I see url http://127.0.0.1:8000/nse/stockdetails/BBTC and in the console I see it tries to load a couple of times and ends with warning

```
Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/nse/stockdetails/BBTC"
```

But if I directly go to the url without Redirect through the app component, it works perfectly. In the App component I have the following.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`${match.url}/index`} component={AIContainer}/>
  <Route path={`${match.url}/equity`} component={EQContainer}/>
  <Route path={`${match.url}/quickstats`} component={StatsContainer}/>
  <Route path={`${match.url}/stockdetails/:ticker`} component={StockSearchDetails}/>
  <Route component={ScreenContainer}/>
</Switch>
```

I know the example in docs does not use Redirect to nested route. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,its inifinite loop as you are not resetting the `visibleContainerProp` to other value(s).Its stick with `4`.

Instead of

```
if(visibleContainerProp == 4){          
  return <Redirect to={`${match.url}/stockdetails/${searchticker}`} />
}
```

dispatch an action first  which will reset `visibleContainerProp`

```
if(visibleContainerProp == 4){          
       dispatch({ type : 'UPDATE_MY_PARAM_TO_RESET_REDIRECTION'})
      return <Redirect to={`${match.url}/stockdetails/${searchticker}`} />
}
```

In App component,read `visibleContainerProp` via `mapStateToProps`,which will help you for managing 
`visibleContainerProp==4` condition and avoid looping redirection.

EDIT :

dispatch an action `redirectAction`.call it from appropriate component life cycle based on your requirement by checking the condition `if(visibleContainerProp == 4)`

```
redirectAction(redirectUrl){

          /this will update `visibleContainerProp` to some other value
         dispatch({ type : 'UPDATE_MY_PARAM_TO_RESET_REDIRECTION'});
         //create history object and push the next url
         history.push(`${match.url}/stockdetails/${searchticker}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Riyaj

Mutating states in render is not allowed and I get 
    Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: Yes. That's how it's done in the docs. So I followed the example

Comment: After redirection which component you want to render?

Comment: I want to render StockSearchDetails component. Same as in the switch statement. So the <Route path={`${match.url}/stockdetails/:ticker`} component={StockSearchDetails}/>. I should say the trick above did work though bit I am wondering if there is a pattern compliant solution to this.

Comment: I suppose there are no further answers forthcoming even after addition of couple more tags. So I am going to accept your answer as it worked. Probably I asked a wrong question or may be in a wrong way. Nevertheless, you solved my immediate problem. So thank you very much. Cheers.